# Problem with the output of a function I program

Tags: programming, function-construction

(*This is the function that I programmed*)

```
Zm2[Z_, nk_] := (zm2 = 0;
   For[i = 0, i < Length[Z], i++, zm2 += nk[[i]] *Z[[i]]* Z[[i]];];
   Return[zm2];);
```

(*These are the input data*)

```
z = List[82, 57, 40, 22, 41, 8];
n = List[0.1973, 0.002, 0.1068, 0.0930, 0.002, 0.5989];
```

(*Hear I evaluate the function in the input data*)

```
Zm2[z, n]
```

(*This is the result*)

```
1552.4 + List^3
```

I need to remove the `+List^3`; the value 1552.4 is correct, but I can't use the function for further calculations with the `+List^3`.

PLEASE IF SOMEONE CAN HELPE ME WITH THAT, THIS IS FOR MY THESIS WORK.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 4):

First problem, subscripts start with 1 in Mathematica, not 0 like in many other languages.

One alternative

```
z = List[82, 57, 40, 22, 41, 8];
n = List[0.1973, 0.002, 0.1068, 0.0930, 0.002, 0.5989]; 
Zm2[Z_, nk_] := Sum[nk[[i]]*Z[[i]]^2, {i, 1, Length[Z]}];
Zm2[z, n]
```

which gives 1590.73

Or perhaps just using

```
Total[n*z^2]
```

which gives the same result, but that uses different features of Mathematica